# Could html be allowed in Price Option labels

Tags: price-sets

I have a set of radio buttons for a Membership price set.

It would look better if we could break up the longish list, and the easy solution would be adding in an "hr" at end of a label.

That is clearly not possible currently. What would be required to do so and are there some/many/lots of good reasons not to consider this as an 'improvement' to core?